# Why does instance variable assignment within a a model require self?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, helper

The famous tutorial uses self to assign user to an instance variable.

```
module SessionsHelper

  def sign_in(user)
    remember_token = User.new_remember_token
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
    user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.hash(remember_token))
    self.current_user = user
  end



   def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
   end
 end
```

Why wouldn't the following be valid? The book says this type of assignment would create a local variable.

```
module SessionsHelper

  def sign_in(user)
    remember_token = User.new_remember_token
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
    user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.hash(remember_token))
    @current_user = user
  end



  ###def current_user=(user)
 #   @current_user = user
  # end
# end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `@current_user = user` in `sign_in` method then it should definitely work which is as good as calling the `commented method current_user=`. `@current_user` is not a local variable, it is an instance variable.

> *The book says this type of assignment would create a local variable.*

Book is not talking about `@current_user = user` BUT about `current_user = user` (Notice without prefix `@`) which will set a local variable `current_user` and not call the instance method `current_user=`.

When you call `self.current_user = user`,  then `self` is the explicit receiver so Ruby knows that `current_user=` is a method and not a local variable.

Comment: So in rails calling current_user(user) would not be the equivalent to self.current_user = user ?

Comment: It will give you error as it will look for a method named `current_user`(Notice without `=`) with 1 argument.